# When to send the 'goodbye' email?

Tags: new-job, farewell

When is the best time to send my team the 'goodbye' email? I've been with the company for 6 months and have built a good professional relationship with a few colleagues on the team.

Should it be 1 week prior to the last day? The last day?

Comment: Last day is by far the most usual, in my experience.

Comment: just before you leave if you must send one, most people I know haven't bothered

Comment: Send it on the morning of the last day, so those who feel the need can reply.  If there are people you like, speak to them before you leave, so they know you're going.

Comment: In the UK I feel they sometimes send it some days in advance when it's all confirmed so that people have time to organise an evening for leaving drinks and such :)

Comment: The last thing you do before shutting down your PC for the last time.

Comment: Don't overthink this. Most people don't care. In fact, I have setup an Outlook rule to automatically move mails with "Last Working Day", "Thanks for everything", "Until we meet again..." (and a few other cliched subject lines) to another folder (appropriately named /dev/null). I look at this folder once in a while, and 99% of the time I scratch my head thinking, "Who was that guy? Did I know him?" People who *really* want to bid me a goodbye do so in person.

Comment: Most often I have seen has been a few days before, with a "meet me for beverages at [place] on [usually Friday]"

Answer (score 12):

Usually you do the whole "Goodbye" spiel on your last day. This also includes any email(s) you send.

Doing it before may be awkward, but not exceptionally bad or anything.

Keep in mind that sending goodbye emails has fallen out of usage greatly (at least where I live) and may not even be necessary. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: It might not be necessary, but is certainly a nice thing to do. A simple "It's been great working with you" never hurt anyone.

Comment: Just resist temptation to "unload"

Answer (score 6):

When I leave, I send a goodbye email on the afternoon of my last day.

Since I've already gone around and said goodbye in person to the folks I care most about, I just use the email to publicly say thanks and to make sure everyone has my personal contact information.

It also serves to say goodbye to the remote folks I work with, but can't talk to face-to-face.

Answer (score 4):

You should send your Good Bye Email on your last day, about 15 minutes before you leave.

Why ?

It is done to avoid fuss and avoid distracting others. If done at the end of the your day , people do not have the time to react. In the mail , you have specified your contact. So if needed they will contact you. It is just professional to avoid any melodrama/distractions/confrontations. Have seen this done in top 10 financial companies usually

Comment: Sounds pretty arbitrary to me.